# Como cancelar la ejecución de una función Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Me encuentro haciendo un proyecto personal en el que quiero simular un Paint; tengo dos div con sus respectivos iconos de Font Awesome (uno de goma de borrar y el otro de un lápiz). Yo lo que quiero lograr es: al darle click al div del lápiz que dibuje, pero con el mouse (todo esto es en un canvas), y al darle click a la goma de borrar, se va borrando lo dibujado a medida que el mouse presionado pasa. Y logro los dos objetivos pero me encuentro con el inconveniente de que: si presiono primero el lápiz y dibujo, luego uso la goma y borro, y después quiero usar nuevamente usar el lápiz no puedo, la goma se queda en uso constante y no logro hacer que quede desactiva o fuera de uso hasta que le vuelva a dar click al div correspondiente. Dejo el código .js abajo y agradezco cualquier ayuda o colaboración. Desde ya muchas gracias.

```js
//Activar el lapiz
function activePencil(evento) {
    estadoLapiz = true;
    x = evento.offsetX;
    y = evento.offsetY;
}
  
//Desactivar el lapiz
function deactivatePencil() {
    estadoLapiz = false;
}
  
//Para dibujar con el mouse
function drawWithClick(evento) {
    let xFinal = evento.offsetX;
    let yFinal = evento.offsetY;    

    if (estadoLapiz && !estadoGoma) {
        drawLine(inpPalette.value, x, y, xFinal, yFinal);
        x = xFinal;
        y = yFinal;
        return !estadoLapiz;
    }
}

//Activa la goma de borrar
function activeEraser(evento) {
    estadoGoma = true;
    estadoLapiz = false;
    x = evento.offsetX;
    y = evento.offsetY;
}

//Desactiva la goma de borrar
function deactivateEraser() {
    estadoGoma = false;
}

//Para borrar con el mouse
function deleteWithClick(evento){
    x = evento.offsetX;
    y = evento.offsetY;
    
    if (estadoGoma && !estadoLapiz) {
        context.clearRect(x, y, sizeLine, sizeLine);
        return !estadoGoma;
    }
}
lapiz.addEventListener("click", () => {
    drawing.addEventListener("mousedown", activePencil);
    drawing.addEventListener("mousemove", drawWithClick);
    drawing.addEventListener("mouseup", deactivatePencil);
});

gomaBorrar.addEventListener("click", () => {
    drawing.addEventListener("mousedown", activeEraser);
    drawing.addEventListener("mousemove", deleteWithClick);
    drawing.addEventListener("mouseup", deactivateEraser);
});
```

Comment: Creo que en la función de activePencil activas el lapicero, pero no desactivas el eraser. Mientras que en activeEraser activas eraser y desactivas pencil. Luego condicionas con esto if (estadoLapiz && !estadoGoma) en drawWithClick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La idea de guardar los estados no es mala, solo realizas la acción cuando esta está habilitada. El tema de habilitar y deshabilitar acciones lo debería manejar cada acción (lapiz, goma). Pero en cuanto a los listeners, se deberían crear una sola vez y simplemente hacer un `if` si la acción está habilitada. Si creas el listener cada vez que se habilita la función, deberías hacer `removeListener` de las demás acciones, además cada habilitación agrega un nuevo listener. Por ello no es conveniente hacer un `addEventListener` cada vez que habilitan una acción. Aquí dejo un ejemplo mínimo de la idea, espero que se entienda:

```js
let estadoGoma = false; // <-- Esto determina si se hacen o no las acciones definidas en el evento que corresponda
let estadoLapiz = true;

function activePencil() { // <-- cada accion maneja la habilitación de las demás
    estadoGoma = false;
    estadoLapiz = true;
}
  
  
function activeEraser() {
    estadoGoma = true;
    estadoLapiz = false;
}

const estado = document.getElementById("estado");

document.getElementById("goma").addEventListener("click",activeEraser);
document.getElementById("lapiz").addEventListener("click",activePencil);

// Los listeners se pueden crear una sola vez, en este ejemplo hago solo uno para los dos.

window.document.addEventListener("mousemove", ()=>{

    estado.innerHTML = "Estado lapiz: "+estadoLapiz+" |  Estado goma: "+estadoGoma;
  
  if(estadoLapiz){ // <-- como el estado es global, cualquier función lo puede cambiar
    // aqui dibujamos
  }
  
  if(estadoGoma){
   //aqui borramos
  }

});
```

```html
<div id="estado"></div>
<br>
<button id="goma">goma</button>
<br>
<button id="lapiz">lapiz</button>
```

En el ejemplo pongo un solo evento para todas las acciones (`mousemove`) para hacer mas sencillo el concepto, pero la idea sería definir todos los eventos y sus acciones.

En otras palabras, lo que propongo es que siempre estén definidas todas las acciones posibles para cada posible evento y manejar que se hace o deja de hacer en función de los estados.

Comment: Muchas gracias Emmeus, hice uso de un removeEventListener en la función deactivateEraser(), llegue a la conclusión de que era lo que me convenía ya que hice una "depuración" con algunos console.log y me di cuenta que la goma no se desactivaba nunca.

Answer (score 0):

puede ser que no te este tomando el cambio dinámico en la funciones, prueba con esto:

```
lapiz.addEventListener.on("click", function() => {
    drawing.addEventListener("mousedown", activePencil);
    drawing.addEventListener("mousemove", drawWithClick);
    drawing.addEventListener("mouseup", deactivatePencil);
});

gomaBorrar.addEventListener.on("click", function() => {
    drawing.addEventListener("mousedown", activeEraser);
    drawing.addEventListener("mousemove", deleteWithClick);
    drawing.addEventListener("mouseup", deactivateEraser);
});
```

Comment: eso es exactamente igual a lo que ya está haciendo